# How to convert timestamp in Redshift so that I get seconds/milliseconds?

Tags: amazon-redshift, redash

I have a dataframe like:

```
   id      state   city     time
123.04      ny      1    01-10-2021 12:30
123.05      ny      2    01-10-2021 12:30
```

I want the the id that that is associated with the most recent time by state. So I do:

```
select id, state 
from data a 
join (select state, max(time) as most_recent 
      from data group by 1) b on a on a.state = b.state and a.time = b.most_recent)
```

However, I am running into issues where the timestamp is the same. I know that I can do another query to then get the max ID but I would ideally like to just go by timestamp. I know that the ID is assigned in sequential order so if I am able to get the seconds or milliseconds then I will be able to actually get the most recent ID.

Is there way to get seconds/milliseconds or do I have to do another query?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift timestamps have a 1 microsecond resolution - this is part of the data type definition.  If you are not seeing the seconds and fractional seconds it is because of how your bench (/ connection to RS) is presenting the data to you.  The easiest way to see the fractional seconds is to format the timestamp to a string when viewing and then there will not be any reformatting.  For example:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS.US');
```